# Active Record query for latest update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysqli

I got a small problem that can't be fix now by me ^_^ and would like to see your advice.
The problem is only about getting the latest updated of several record from mysql table.
Here is the sample data but the real one has thousands of record.

```
Id  site_id      updated_at               value
1   1            "2012-05-14 09:04:02"    5
2   2            "2012-05-14 09:04:02"    8
3   2            "2012-05-15 09:04:02"    9
4   3            "2012-05-16 09:04:02"    7
5   1            "2012-05-17 09:04:02"    5
6   1            "2012-05-18 09:04:02"    3
```

and I want to have XXXX function that will return

```
Id  site_id      updated_at               value
6   1            "2012-05-18 09:04:02"    3
4   3            "2012-05-16 09:04:02"    7
3   2            "2012-05-15 09:04:02"    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
YourModel.order("updated_at desc").limit(3)
```

Comment: This record just a sample and not only 3 different record. May be I need to find how many different records.

Comment: Well, that line will give you the three latest updated records. If you want another number, just switch the `3` for some other number.

Comment: Your solution is really easy .. I have no idea why I can't find this solution ... thanks

Comment: Your solution can solve in some condition but not all. I just change some data that make your solution unsolve to my question. Sorry for make you mess up with this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model is called `Account`:

```
Account.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts a 
    ON a.site_id = accounts.site_id AND a.value > accounts.value").
  where("a.value IS NULL").order("accounts.updated_at DESC").limit(3)
```